# C++ Initialization types - practical use

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, c++20

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization), there are the following initialization types:

- Value initialization, e.g. `std::string s{};`
- Direct initialization, e.g. `std::string s("hello");`
- Copy initialization, e.g. `std::string s = "hello";`
- List initialization, e.g. `std::string s{'a', 'b', 'c'};`
- Aggregate initialization, e.g. `char a[3] = {'a', 'b'};`
- Reference initialization, e.g. `char& c = a[0];`

From time to time, reading about something I need to understand about C++, I run into one of these types, go to this page, and honestly never gain understanding of all those different types. More importantly, should I really care about it?

So far, I was good to write C++ code without understanding different C++ initialization types.

Can somebody provide examples of situations or code snippets, where knowing about initialization types and writing one initialization code over other will make the code works differently (in perforce or any other aspect)? Not considering cases of making useless copies, of course.

Comment: Initialization in C++ is actually pretty complicated, and it has conflicting rules that can really leave you confused.  Don't fell bad if you have trouble with it, I think everyone does, myself included.  As an example, here is a ~1hr video about just that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs

Comment: Don't forget [Default initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization).

Comment: Obligatory meme https://imgur.com/3wlxtI0

Comment: This is a very interesting question. However, this is a highly subjective question that is likely to invite opinion based responses, as opposed to factual responses. SO's Q&A format is not really suitable for an open-ended discussion of this nature.

Comment: _"is any practical gain to know and understand all those types?"_ if nothing else, you will see them.  It's practical to understand code you are seeing.

Comment: @cigien I'm asking about practical use - so if there is any one can show an example, so it's not really opinion based. Or you can say that question like "how to do N" is also opinion based, as there can be different options how to do N.

Comment: @Random you may want to rephrase your question to not use the opinionated word "practical".  Perhaps remove that one question, since there should only be one question here.

Comment: A question having multiple answers is not a problem at all, since each answer can be judged as to how well it answers the question. The issue with a question like "is there a good reason programmers should care about initialization types?" is that it's very hard to objectively judge any answers. I think your question could be improved so that it invites concrete, objective answers, but in its current form, I'm afraid I don't think it works.

Comment: The last sentence in the question is an improvement. Asking for examples where different kinds of initialization change behavior is reasonable. I would suggest removing the first 2 questions in the last paragraph though, since they're still quite opinion based.

Comment: There is no general answer, but a rope for orientation. When creating. an instance of a type, have a look what data you have, what data you need and how easy for someone (perhaps you in a year) is it to understand that code. Then select the way you feel most comfortable with. And add some pragmatism. For instance: Why allocate and init memory for a string, just to make a copy of it? It like building a house, then build a new one that looks the same and flatten the first one. IMHO it is a waste of resources - cpu cycles and memory.